# Using `json_build_object` to join nested properties

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following,

```
create table product(id serial primary key);
create table product_image(id serial primary key, product_id bigint references product(id));
create table chat(id serial primary key, product_id bigint references product(id));

insert into product values(1), (2), (3);
insert into product_image values(30, 1), (31, 1);
insert into chat values(50, 1), (51, 2);
```

I'm expecting the following result:

```
 chat_id |  product                                 |
---------+------------------------------------------+
      50 |  {"id":1,"images":[{"id":30},{"id":31}]} |
      51 |  {"id":2,"images":[]}                    |
```

Here's what I've tried,

```
select
  c.id as chat_id,
  json_build_object(
    'id', p.id,
    'images', to_jsonb(
        select * from product_image pi
        join product p on p.id = pi.product_id
    )
  ) as product
from chat c
join product p on p.id = c.product_id
join product_image pi on pi.product_id = p.id
```

I feel like I'm close, but I keep catching unexpected results.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is not joined to your outer query. The imo easiest and most straightforward way to achieve this is using only subqueries, using `WHERE` conditions to select only those rows that match the outer object:

```
SELECT
  c.id as chat_id,
  (
    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
      'id', p.id,
      'images', ARRAY(
        SELECT jsonb_build_object(
          'id', pi.id
        )
        FROM product_image pi
        WHERE pi.product_id = p.id
      )
    )
    FROM product p
    WHERE p.id = c.product_id
  ) AS product
FROM chat c
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/remk6cMW))</sup>

Instead of the `ARRAY(…)` subquery syntax, you can also use `jsonb_agg` ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y_vTGW2N)), but it returns `null` instead of an empty array when there are no elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `json_build_object` and `json_agg` as follows :

```
  select
  c.id as chat_id,
  json_build_object(
    'id', p.id,
     'images',  COALESCE(json_agg(
                             json_build_object(
                                  'id', pi.id
                             ) ) FILTER (WHERE pi.id IS NOT NULL), '[]'
                        )
  ) as productt
  from chat c
  left join product p on p.id = c.product_id
  left join product_image pi on pi.product_id = p.id
  group by c.id, p.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cNRC-Aa4)

Comment: That returns an array containing `null` instead of an empty array. It's why I've avoided left joins in my answer :-)

Comment: Thats correct, thanks for the remark :) I have fixed it